# csvwrite in loop with numbered filenames in matlab

Tags: matlab, csv, printf, export-to-csv, pass-by-value

kinda new to matlab here, searching the [csvwrite tutorial](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/csvwrite.html)  and some of the existing webportals regarding my question couldn't find a way to pass my variables by value to the output file names while exporting in csv; providing my bellow scripts, i would like to have the output files something like `output_$aa_$dd.csv` which aa and dd are respectively the first and second for counters of the scripts.

```
for aa=1:27
for dd=1:5
    M_Normal=bench(aa,dd).Y;
    for j=1:300
        randRand=M_Normal(randperm(12000,12000));
            for jj = 1:numel(randMin(:,1));  % loops over the rand numbers
                vv= randMin(jj,1);  % gets the value
                randMin(jj,j+1)=min(randRand(1:vv));    % get and store the min of the selction in the matix
            end
    end
    csvwrite('/home/amir/amir_matlab/sprintf(''%d%d',aa, bb).csv',randMin);
end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String concatenation in MATLAB is done like a matrix concatenation. For example

```
a='app';
b='le';
c=[a,b] % returns 'apple'
```

Hence, in your problem, the full path can be formed this way.

```
['/home/amir/amir_matlab/',sprintf('%d_%d',aa,bb),'.csv']
```

Furthermore, it is usually best not to specify the file separator explicitly, so that your code can be implemented in other operating systems. I suggest you write the full path as

```
fullfile('home','amir','amir_matlab',sprintf('%d_%d.csv',aa,bb))
```

Cheers.

Comment: cheers buddy ;) and i think I have to mention the matrix for the output as well at the end, right ? `fullfile('home','amir','amir_matlab',sprintf('%d_%d.csv',aa,bb), randMin)`

Comment: Yes, as the second argument to `csvwrite`.